# Django AllAuth - Google - choose username

Tags: python, django, google-authentication, django-allauth

We are using `Django-allauth` to allow users to signup and login using Google.

The problem is that it automatically chooses  first name from Google account as a `username`.

Is it possible to make users to fill the username manually?

I didn't find such settings in [Allauth-google](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#google) docs.

These are `ACCOUNT_` settings from `settings.py`

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username_email"
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_COOLDOWN = 1
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION = True
ACCOUNT_PRESERVE_USERNAME_CASING = False
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH = 4
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
```

There is no such setting starting `SOCIALACCOUNT_` in Docs.

Comment: There is a way to create a custom unique username. But i think customer to choose a username is not possible since the social login usually won't have a flow for that.

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal Yes, I know that username can be unique, I'm curious if there is such built-in option in allauth.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that allauth doesn't try to bypass the signup form.

In settings.py:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = False
```

This will redirect the user to the default signup page and have a signup form where the user can choose their username. [SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP django-allauth readthedocs explanation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html?highlight=SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP#configuration)

If you want, you can also customize the signup form for a user signing up with a social account by doing the following:

In settings.py:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'signup': 'mysite.forms.MyCustomSocialSignupForm',
}
```

In your models file:

```
from allauth.socialaccount.forms import SignupForm
class MyCustomSocialSignupForm(SignupForm):

    def save(self, request):

        # Ensure you call the parent class's save.
        # .save() returns a User object.
        user = super(MyCustomSocialSignupForm, self).save(request)

        # Add your own processing here.

        # You must return the original result.
        return user
```

and then you can add any custom changes to this form that are needed

[django-allauth readthedocs for overriding default signup form](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#socialaccount-forms)